# Computer refuses to boot from HDD after BIOS changes

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, boot, bios

TL;DR question at the bottom 
I downloaded an instance of `Linux Cinnamon Mint` onto a jump drive using `YUMI` so I could work on some programs that are optimized for `Linux`. I got into the `BIOS` of my `Windows 10` laptop and turned off `safe boot` and turned on `Legacy boot`, so I could boot from the `USB`. It was working fine and I was able to get into the instance of `Linux Mint` and I did some good work. 
I then try to boot up my computer and it takes me to the screen where I can choose between the `Internal HDD` or the `Linux` instance. I choose `Internal HDD` and it just gives me a black screen with a hanging `Booting...` message. So I hard shut down my computer, take out the `USB` and start my computer again and it just says `No Boot Device Found. Press any key to reboot the machine` and so I shut my computer down again and I get into the `One Time Boot Menu` by pressing `F12` and I select `Boot from Windows Boot Manager` and I was able to boot my computer fine that way, but I had to do that cumbersome act every time I wanted to turn my computer on. So I turned `legacy boot` off and then turned `safe boot` back on and I was able to boot `Windows` normally, but I wasn't able to boot from my `USB`. 
 
 
TL;DR: Is there a way for me to both boot from my `USB` and `HDD` without having to go through cumbersome `BIOS` procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to boot your version of Linux without `Secure Boot` off since it's not certified by Microsoft. However, me saying that there is a way to make it work but you have to do it manually using `reFInd` which you can find [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and sign the `kernel` with `MOK`. Click [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) for a full guide on how to do this.

So in summary you won't be able to boot Linux unless `Secure Boot` is off and because `Secure Boot` is off, you won't be able to boot Windows 10. So to be able to boot into both with `Secure Boot` enabled, you need to find a Linux Distribution that is digitally signed by Microsoft (because Linux Mint isn't) such as Ubuntu or use my suggestion above to keep Linux Mint and boot both.

Comment: with secure boot off, will I be able to still boot Windows and Linux with no issue? Or do I have to gerrymander the BIOS every time?

Comment: Updated my answer for you @AdamMcGurk

Answer (score 0):

Its not only a Secure boot Problem,
EFI can boot from devices partitioned with GPT or MBR Partition Tables.
Some BIOS' (legacy boot) can not do this at all,also in legacy mode it is impossible to boot the EFI Partition since it is a seperate Partition and not in the MBR,see : (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)

> On legacy BIOS-based systems, the first sector of a partition is
>   loaded into memory and execution is transferred to this code. UEFI
>   firmware does not execute the code in the MBR, except when booting in
>   legacy BIOS mode through the Compatibility Support Module (CSM).[3]

Either you have to switch between EFI and Legacy Boot every time you use this stick, or you create a stick with an EFI partition capable of beeing booted from EFI with disabled secureboot,this stick however will not be able to be booted in legacy mode or on older Hardware using a BIOS